# How to disambiguate global and local methods in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to use kind of SwiftUI-like functional style of configuring the UI, for example by providing [a global] method **hide(view: UIView)** instead of writing **view.isHidden = true**.

Now this works fine but for reverse logic I want to have the global method **show()** but within context of an UIViewController it conflicts with the class method **show(sender: Any)**.

Is there any language trick I can you in order not to have to write MyAppName.show() each time I use it?

Comment: Eh, there's nothing particularly functional about doing that. And besides, "functional" isn't an inherently positive quality, anymore than "slipperiness" of a surface. Sometimes it's good (on a slide), and sometimes it's bad (brake pads). `view.isHidden = true` is much better, IMO. Otherwise you'll end up writing code like `shouldBeHidden ? hide(view) : show(view)`, as opposed to `view.isHidden = shouldBeHidden`.

Comment: Agreed; there's nothing "functional" about what you're describing. You likely mean "declarative." The answer is to rename your "show" function something else, or move all of this outside of UIViewControllers (which is likely a more powerful solution).

Comment: Oka, "declarative" is better, your're right. Still hide(something) is very straightforward. And I do not have to write "shouldBeHidden" - that's the whole point - when you need to hide you write hide(), need to show, you write show().  Constructions especially like view.isHidden = false are mind boggling

Comment: You can use some other method name instead of show like display(); and you don't have to repeat module name again and again.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel Code like that is *really* not mind boggling, it's pervasive throughout languages with properties, like Swift, Objective C, C#, and even in languages without them, people do a similar thing with setters `view.setHidden(true)`.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel My point is, at some point you'll have to determine a view's visibility based off a boolean condition of some sort. For example, image an online shopping app where you want to show a "on sale!" banner on an item, if it is indeed, on sale. You would have something like `if product.IsOnSale { show(saleBanner) } else { hide(saleBanner) }`, whereas the boolean property lets you just write: `saleBanner.isHidden = !product.isOnSale`

Comment: @Alexander unfortunately, pervasiveness is not a prove of an advantage. There is a semantic difference: either I express my intentions "I want a view to disappear" or i'm thinking in terms of "setting a property". Is it done over property or not, those are technical details I do not need to know.

Comment: @Alexander if I write hide(view, when: condition) then when condition is false, view will become visible.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel "unfortunately, pervasiveness is not a prove of an advantage." Indeed, I'm not saying that it must be good, I was merely refuting that it was "mind boggling." It's really not.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel A property is a feature of an interface, no different from a method or a subscript. It's not an implementation detail, because it doesn't tell you absolutely anything about the implementation, certainly no more than a method or subscript would. It doesn't, for example, imply for example, that there's some stored property called `hidden`. You have no idea what it does, internally.

Comment: @alexander  double negation (isHidden = false) is not something our brain processes easily. Why impose harder challenges on it? it's overloaded already anyway.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel I don't really think you addressed anything I said. But anyways, you're free to disagree, just don't mistake yourself into thinking this is mind boggling or somehow exceptional. It's incredibly common API design.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is a bit inaccurate. You already know how to disambiguate it. The question is about how to do so without repeating the module name. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any such way.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Swift compiler seems to be overreacting, as one method has 2 arguments and my method has 1 argument. What's the reason to write "nearly matches" and breaking compilation is unclear to me.

However, I found the solution:

```
extension UIViewController{
    func show(_ view: UIView) { view.isHidden = false }
}
```